# Angular JS - confirm dialog with coffee script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to use the $confirm service provided by angular. The following coffee script throws error:

```
    $scope.showConfirmation = ->
        $confirm({text: 'Can we test?'})
        .then () -> $log.info("test")
```

Error:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24confirmProvider%20%3C-%20%24confirm **Cause : <div class="ng-scope" ng-view=""**>
```

Comment: you haven't injected the confirm module into your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here from `$confirm` docs for how to inject the service for use throughout your app: https://schlogen.github.io/angular-confirm/

1. Add service to your module

`angular.module('myApp', ['angular-confirm']);`

2. Inject into your controller

`.controller("Controller", function($confirm) {`